# puppetlabs-java Oracle Failed to apply catalog: No title provided and :file is not a valid resource reference

Tags: java, puppet

## Question

Please advise what the cause of the issue in puppet apply using puppetlab java manifest to install Oracle JDK.

## Issue

[Puppetlab Java](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-java) has the example below to install Oracle JDK.

```
include java
java::oracle { 'jdk8' :
    ensure  => 'present',
    version => '8',
    java_se => 'jdk',
}
```

Just copied as is in java.pp and run puppet apply and got the error.

```
$ sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet apply --verbose /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/java.pp
Info: Loading facts
Info: Loading facts
Info: Loading facts
Info: Loading facts
Notice: Scope(Java::Oracle[jdk6]): Destination is /tmp/jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin
Notice: Scope(Java::Oracle[jdk8]): Destination is /tmp/jdk-8u51-linux-x64.rpm
Notice: Compiled catalog for puppet.demo.local in environment production in 0.32 seconds
Info: Applying configuration version '1464427680'
Error: Failed to apply catalog: No title provided and :file is not a valid resource reference
```

The other example below worked fine.

```
class { 'java' :
  package => 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel',
}
```

## Environment

CentOS 7 64 bit
Puppet (open source) 4.5.0

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with the puppet-archive module currently released on the forge (see https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-archive/issues/166)

This has been fixed in https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-archive/pull/167

There should be a bugfix release soon, but in the mean time, you can download the latest version of the module and use the upstream and it should work: `git clone https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-archive archive` in your modules directory.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Run git clone but puppet apply shows "Evaluation Error: Unknown function: 'ensure_resource'. at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/java/manifests/oracle.pp:83:3". Perhaps I did something wrong...

Comment: My bad. Correction: Renamed existing archive/ and run git clone in the /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
/ directory), restarted puppet/puppetserver services, and run apply but the same result. "Error: Failed to apply catalog: No title provided and :file is not a valid resource reference".

Comment: Can you try completely deleting the archive module, running the clone again and then run a `puppet module list` to see if it's showing the old or the new tag?

Comment: Hi Peter, Run "rm -r -f archive &&  sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet apply --verbose /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/java.pp
" but still the same error. "Notice: Scope(Java::Oracle[jdk8]): Destination is /tmp/jdk-8u51-linux-x64.rpm
Notice: Compiled catalog for puppet.demo.local in environment production in 0.33 seconds
Info: Applying configuration version '1464651973'
Error: Failed to apply catalog: No title provided and :file is not a valid resource reference".